# ServiceStack: Getting FileNotFoundException when properties are null?

Tags: servicestack

I am using ServiceStack and have discovered something odd. I am getting the `FileNotFoundException` on `System.Numerics.Vectors` when the WS Dto contains some `null` values. For example, I have a Dto called "GetBookingSolutions", that looks like this:

```
    [Route(BookingWizard.BASE_PATH + "getbookingsolution", Verbs = "POST", Summary = "Sends booking spec to request server to create/plan the booking")]
public class GetBookingSolution : IReturn<GetBookingSolutionResponse>
{
    public DateTime TimeWanted { get; set; }
    public uint AddressFrom { get; set; }
    // ...
    public Dictionary<uint, int> Equipment { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<uint, int> CoTravellers { get; set; }
}
```

The last two are Dictionaries and thus objects that are nullable. If the sending client sends a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "TimeWanted": "2018-12-10T09:05:00.000Z",
  "AddressFrom": 14427162,
  "CoTravellers": null,
  "Equipment": null
}
```

then I get the Exception, as can be seen below. The service implementation is never executed, so the code is never reached. Instead, I get the Exception in the `UncaughtExceptionHandlers`.

If the JSON instead looks like this:

```
{
  "TimeWanted": "2018-12-10T09:05:00.000Z",
  "AddressFrom": 14427162,
}
```

or if the dictionaries are populated:

```
{
  "TimeWanted": "2018-12-10T09:05:00.000Z",
  "AddressFrom": 14427162,
  "CoTravellers": {
    "13486513": 2,
    "13486515": 1
   },
  "Equipment": {
   "13424459": 2,
  }
}
```

then the error does not appear. Why is it like this? Is it a bug or what is the suggestion here? a `null` value is appropriate for those properties, if they are not set by the end-user.

```html
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.SpanHelpers.SequenceEqual(Byte& first, Byte& second, NUInt length)
   at System.MemoryExtensions.Equals(ReadOnlySpan`1 span, ReadOnlySpan`1 other, StringComparison comparisonType)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer.EatValue(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJson.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJson(ReadOnlySpan`1 value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonReader.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<GetParseSpanFn>b__0(ReadOnlySpan`1 v)
   at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromSpan(Type type, ReadOnlySpan`1 value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.DefaultMemory.Deserialize(MemoryStream ms, Boolean fromPool, Type type, DeserializeStringSpanDelegate deserializer)
   at ServiceStack.Text.DefaultMemory.<DeserializeAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.<CreateRequestAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.<CreateRequestAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a runtime dependency issue and has got nothing to do with null in your DTO, that's just what's triggering a code-path that requires the **System.Numerics.Vectors** dependency it can't load. In this case calling the `System.MemoryExtensions.Equals()` extension method.

There seems to be a [few issues](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=FileNotFoundException%20System.Numerics.Vectors) with this Exception and it looks like [this GitHub Thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30106) has some workarounds you can try.

Comment: Alright, I'll have to change the JSON instead, that long GitHub thread doesnt makes sense to me =)